# RTF形式の画像コードを画像として保存したい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

RTF形式の画像コード（{\pict中にある連続したとても長い半角英数字）を画像として保存するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

visual studio express 2015 (windows 10 64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework内のクラスだと`FlowDocument`が`.rtf`形式の読み込みに対応しています。

```
var fd = new FlowDocument();
var tr = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
tr.Load(new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test.rtf", FileMode.Open), DataFormats.Rtf);
```

読込後に`FlowDocument.Blocks`の中を探せばどこかに画像があるはずです。

ですが`FlowDocument`は`System.Windows.Controls.Image`型で画像をデコードするため、上記のコードはWPFアプリケーションのUIスレッドでしか実行できません。

ですのでWindows Formsなどでは裏でWPFアプリを起動する必要があります。

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // WPFアプリをバックグラウンドで起動する
        if (Application.Current == null)
        {
            var th = new Thread(() => new Application()
            {
                ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
            }.Run());

            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();

            while (Application.Current == null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }

        // WPFスレッドで処理を行う
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var fd = new FlowDocument();
            var tr = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
            tr.Load(new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test.rtf", FileMode.Open), DataFormats.Rtf);

            foreach (var b in fd.Blocks)
            {
                FindImage(b);
            }
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    finally
    {
        // プログラム終了時にWPFアプリケーションを終了しておく
        Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Invoke(Application.Current.Shutdown);
    }
}

private static void FindImage(TextElement e)
{
    // FlowDocumentに含まれる型ごとに内部を走査する

    var para = e as Paragraph;
    if (para != null)
    {
        foreach (var i in para.Inlines)
        {
            FindImage(i);
        }
        return;
    }

    // 画像はInlineUIContainer→Image
    var uic = e as InlineUIContainer;
    if (uic != null)
    {
        var img = uic.Child as Image;
        if (img != null)
        {
            var bmp = img.Source as BitmapSource;

            if (bmp != null)
            {
                // TODO: ここで画像に対する処理を行う 表示サイズとデコード語のサイズが違うのでリサイズが必要

                // ファイルに書き出す場合
                var fn = bmp.GetHashCode() + ".png";
                var pbe = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                pbe.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fn, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    pbe.Save(fs);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}*{2}, {3}*{4}", fn, img.Width, img.Height, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    // TODO: 他の要素にも対応する

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```